# Acceso a servidor web local con linux

Tags: linux, apache, dns

he creado uns ervidor web con apache, php5, etc en una Raspberry 3.
Tengo 2 virtualhost, uno alojado en un pendrive con nombre "servername" pruebas.com
Otri con nombre "pruba1" está alojado en un la carpeta html raiz /var/www/html/prueba1

la raspberry tiene la ip local 192.1c8.110

No se como invocar a pruebas.com o prueba1

Poque cuando escribo 192.168.1.110/pruebas.com
da error "Not found"
porque busca la carpeta pruebas.com dentro del raiz html(/var/www..)

He modificado el host de windows desde el que trato de acceder a la raspi.
hot:
192.168.1.110 pruebas.com

---

Cuando escribo pruebas.com en el navegador va al index de la raspi, es decir a la principal., Pero no a la configuración del virtualhos

Perdonar el ladrillo. ¿ Como puedo acceder a cada virtualhost desde win ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

busca en google algo como "raspberry linux configure virtual host".
Revisa esto
https://www.stewright.me/2013/08/add-virtual-hosts-and-subdomains-to-your-raspberry-pi-apache2-server/

Comment: Lo tengo así mas o menos, excepto los <Directory>. 
La cuestión es ¿ Como llamo a uno de los virtualhost creados, desde otro ordenador local ?

Comment: Si quieres conectarte de forma remota a la raperry debes colocar el virtual host como publico, y eso se hace configurando el <Directory> colocando AllowOverrideAll  y AllowFromAll (que da acceso a todos) como sale en esta imagen del link anterior https://i1.wp.com/www.stewright.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/nano.jpg?w=697&ssl=1

Comment: No se que sistema operativo tienes en la rasperry, pero busca sobre "configuración de configuracion en linux/ubuntu/debian etc" .

Comment: Aqui un link en debian https://www.regoremor.com/plataformas/linux/configuracion-de-virtualhost-en-linux-debian-con-apache2/